# H-Bridge power supply

Tags: h-bridge

I need to separately power the transist MOSFET with a higher voltage than maximum VDD of the driver MOSFET.
Is the diagram correct?
 Will the driver fully open the transistor?

[image: Half-bridge]
[TC4428 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422G.pdf)
[AOD603A Datasheet](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD603A.pdf)

Comment: That will blow the PMOSFET to pieces. Check out its Vgs(max) in the datasheet, or go back to the 14.4V supply in your other question.

Comment: Max Vgs is +/- 20V.

Comment: "Will the driver fully open the transistor?" is unclear -- either you're referring to "open circuit", as in "turned off", or you're referring to "open like a valve" as in "turned on".  "Will the driver turn the transistor off fully?" is much more clear.

Comment: And 40V - 14.4V > 20V. Let alone 40V - 0V.

Comment: This is an EE problem and not about a hydraulic valve so use the correct words. If in doubt, use activate or deactivate.

Answer (score 1):

For the high side PMOS, with **Supply voltage above Vgs_max** you are going to want to look into an open-drain, open-collector approach. Something like this could work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2PjVM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Zener Voltage should be smaller than Vgs_max but a bit larger than Vgs(th)
- R_on will influence turn-on speed and stability
- R_off will influence turn-off speed and stability

Remember to check how much each component will dissipate and stay within bounds.

The first nmos is the one that provides this open-drain approach to activation, this does not have to be a FET it could also be a bipolar transistor. Its drain-source or collector-emitter max voltage will need to be able to handle the HV as when it is turned off it will be at that value.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment you don't want to do that :D
Also, well, Microchip is not exactly famous for their gate drivers; they are fine but if you look around there's way much better IMHO.

First of all you don't ever put pull-up/pull-down on the gate lines of driven MOSFET: you'll steer away current from the driver, which already has a push/pull stage of its own.

If you did that because you've seen jerks at power on/off, use a gate driver with proper UV lockout.

Second issue: you forgot, as the comments said, the maximum Vgs of your MOSFETs. The P-channels will see 40V when driven, which is quite the double of their max rating.

These days when working with more than about 15V power supplies the standard practice is to *not* use P-channels but N-channels with a pumped driver. They use a charge pump (most of the time is internal) to generate a suitable voltage for the upper side MOSFET. There are special processes involved so these can often handle hundreds of volts on the high side (after that you'll better to seek isolation).

Many manufacturers make these, they are often made as one ICs for bridge leg or three legs in a package for brushless control. Maybe some full bridge driver in a package too.

Another *huge* advantage of these 'leg drivers' is that they usually have shoot through protection: you *definitely* do not want the top and bottom FETs in conduction at the same time! And they take some time to switch too, so you'll need a feature called 'dead period insertion'. Many PWM generators already do that but it's nice to have it in the drivers, just in case.