# How to use a MOSFET to switch up to its Vds rated specs (e.g. 100 or 150 V)?

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, fet, p-channel

So I'm still learning (old dusty ETE degree I finally got around to making use of lately), so be nice please. I get a ton of snark sometimes when I post a question on here. But then there's always one or two nice people with a helpful response. Please be on of them.

So I've gotten comfortable using Fairchild FQP12P10 P-FETs and FQPF45N15V2-D N-FETs in some DIY circuitry in an RV I'm building. It all works great because I was always using 60 V signals (48 V nominal lithium bank charges at up to 58 V so I just estimate 60 V max) to do various switching of 11-15 V signals (vehicle's starter battery) for all kinds of typical 12 V nominal devices. All of that has gone well. I often just use a 30 V Zener to lower the 60 V signal to 30 V, and the rest is easy. My circuits consume very little power (1-2 Wh per day), which is important for the application.

But now I have a need to switch a very low current (~10 mA) 60 V load that I have no access to on its ground side. In other words I can provide it with +60 V or not, but I can't take its connection to ground and run it into my circuitry. It's just not possible. The good news is the load does share a ground with two possible source(s) I'd like to use to do the switching.

My P-FETs are rated for -100 V drain to source, and my N-FETs can do 150 V. But how would I ever take advantage of that and switch a 60 V load if both the P and the N have Voltage gate to source of +/- 30 V max? Again, with the constraint that the circuit must output +60 V to the load, but after that it's out of my hands aside from knowing the load will only draw a few mA before terminating at its own path to ground that I can't access (the load has a direct path to 2/0 cabling for ground, no sticking resistors on that, lol).

I have the following sources to work with for driving the gate: the 60 V lithium bank, and a 12 V starter battery bank. I presumably would want to use the 60 V lithium bank and maybe a zener, but I can't find a way to get a gate-source voltage that stays within bounds of my +/-30 V limitation while still being able to switch this 60V load from its positive input side.

I have a manual rotary switch solution, but I'd really want to do this with FETs so I can integrate it with other circuitry like Bluetooth smart phone controllers, etc. All of that I can figure out if I can just get a diagram on how to switch 60 V as described above.

Usually when I post a question like this it gets dumped on, "not enough info" or endless questions that lead down rabbit holes to nowhere. But what the heck, I thought I'd try again. Sometimes one or two people drop by with exactly what I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, about half what you wrote doesn't really shed light on things and could just be removed. The term you want is "high-side PMOS switching" combined with something like "max Vgs"
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547947/h-bridge-power-supply/548032#548032

Comment: This does not makes sense _"very little power (1-2 W per day"_. W is already J/s so per day does not work. +1 on what @DKNguyen said, you should cut away the majority of your question and draw a schematic of what your core problem is.

Comment: Use the PMOS as a high-side switch with the same 30V zener to limit Vgs. You don't need to hook directly up to the load's ground wire to switch the PMOS - and convenient ground connection will work just fine. If you want you could also add in the NMOS as an inverter so that your switching logic is 'high' == ON.

Comment: @brhans Thank you for being that helpful one! Three snarky replies and then finally your helpful response. Much appreciated. If I use a 30V Zener at the PMOS gate then Vgs is 30V - 60V = -30V, which is right at the max spec for the gate. I hate to be so close to the max.  I guess I can try to source some with higher Vgs values. But is this what you meant? Just run that close to the limit? Thanks again! If you post as an answer and help me finalize this, I'll gladly vote it up. Cheers.

Comment: @winny I meant my circuits often run at about 3mA at 12.5V or ~38mW. I was just multiplying that by 24 = ~1W to get a sense of how many watts were being drained per day, but maybe I meant Wh per day? Can you help clarify what the right term is for this? I added all of that extra language because when I post very short questions, even with schematics, I get endless "you need to add more clarity or detail" comments. There's so much criticism and judgement and "you're doing it wrong" on this forum. Where is the friendly teacher spirit? I don't get it. Open a beer. Have a margarita. Life is good!

Comment: @BeachInMexico Correct, that would be Wh. As for a high side switch, I don't see that as relevant though. Peak output current and if there are any limitations in quiescent current for biasing the high side switch would be though. Can you clear up your question a bit?

Comment: You only need to apply the Vgs to achieve the rated RDson, usually 15V. Ignore Vgsth. It's not useful when used as a switch. Don't source a higher Vgs PMOS. You probably won't find one. Source a lower voltage zener (15V). The reason for so much criticisms is when you spend a lot of time reading questions, it gets really old when you see so many not know how to ask clear questions that don't require you to be in the head of the one writing. It's more than half the battle most of the time. You run into that way more on Electrical SE than Physics or Engineering SE for some reason.

Comment: You can also use N-channels on the top side with… suitable gate driving. Performance are often way better than the P-channels, it's a physical thing

Comment: @BeachInMexico multiplying watts by hours does gives watt-hours

Comment: @BeachInMexico Please add a schematic (there is a tool if you edit the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your PMOS as a high-side switch, along with a zener to limit the V<sub>GS</sub> applied to the PMOS, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmy9YV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your observation that a 30V zener puts it right on the Vgs limit for the PMOS is correct, and I'd probably use a 15-20V zener here - it's well over the 4V V<sub>GSth</sub> point where the PMOS is only just barely turning on, but also safely below the 30V limit.

If you'd prefer to flip the logic such that a 'high' input switches the load on, then you can use an NMOS an an inverter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZjuen.png)</sup>

You don't need to connect the ground point of the control circuit directly to the ground of the load. Any convenient ground will work just fine for these circuits.

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was after! Brhans for the win!

Comment: In the the first drawing, why is R3 needed?

Comment: To make the PMOS switch off when you release the button. Without R3 you'd be relying on the reverse leakage through the zener to discharge the PMOS's gate capacitance.

Comment: Thank you! I want to fully understand what's happening in the circuit. Should I post a new question? I built a test circuit on a 12V breadboard with a 4.7V zener, R3=10k, R2=1K. Vgs is 0V when the button is open (gate is at 12V, source is at 12V so 12-12=0) and -4.7V with button closed (zener clips 12V to 7.3V, and 7.3-12 = -4.7V). That makes sense. But if I remove R3, Vgs is still 0V button open, and -4.7V button closed. However the gate voltage relative to ground is on odd 9.8V button open, so 9.8-12 = 2.2, which is not what I observe. Is this due to the zener reverse leakage you mentioned?

Comment: What you're seeing with no R3 is that your multimeter is acting as a high-value resistance (probably somewhere in the mega-ohms range) and that it's pulling the gate voltage down a little when you make that measurement. The reverse leakage current through the zener flows through your multimeter, so the 9.8V is a result of that current flowing. It's not enough current to put the zener into its reverse-breakdown 'normal' operating range (otherwise you'd see 4.7V across the zener).

Comment: With R3 present, R3 and your multimeter form a voltage divider when making that Gate-to-ground voltage measurement - but since R3 has a value so much smaller than your multimeter, almost the entire voltage drop is across the multimeter, and only a few mV across R3.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, Brhans! I'd never have guessed it was the multimeter. Is there anything wrong with relying on the zener's reverse leakage and skipping R3? Does that introduce some risk that the circuit might not function properly, or damage the zener?

Comment: Relying on the zener's (possibly unpredictable) small reverse leakage current can make the PMOS's turn-off behavior a slow 'ramp' rather than a nice sharp switching operation - R3 should be sized to discharge the PMOS's gate capacitance 'quickly'. That 'ramp' also increases power-dissipation in the PMOS while it's turning off. If a slow turn-off ramp is something you actually want then it would be better & more predictable to add a capacitor (with a value some orders of magnitude greater than the PMOS's gate capacitance) in parallel with R3.